# How to fix " ERROR: Could not build wheels for matplotlib" in " pip install nuscenes-devkit "?

Tags: matplotlib, pyproject.toml

I installed the nuScenes library according to the method of the "github" site, but twice in the installation process, once in the execution of the "requirements.txt"  installation and once in the execution of "pip install nuscenes-devkit" , I got the error "ERROR: Could not build wheels for matplotlib, which is required" I came across "to install pyproject.toml-based projects" .

and according to the instructions on this site and other sites but it didn't help!!! .
I updated "pip" and I also ran "pip install matplotlib==3.2.1", but it didn't help!!!
I don't know exactly what the problem is and how to fix it?!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQmu4.png)

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. All packages are installed as precompiled binaries. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/). **If you are using Anaconda, do not use `pip` to install packages that exist within the `conda` ecosystem.** Use `conda install package`. Only use `pip` if the package is not available with `conda install`. Using `pip` can potentially wreck your installation because `pip` and `conda` do not manage dependencies in the same way.

Comment: It looks like you are using python 3.11, which only came out last year.  Matplotlib v3.2.1 came out in 2020, so there is no guarantee it would be compatible with latest python.  If you really need the old Matplotlib version, it might be worth trying with an older python version.  This page suggests it would work with up  to python v3.8 https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib/3.2.1/

Comment: In fact nuScenes themselves recommend to use python 3.7 https://github.com/nutonomy/nuscenes-devkit/blob/master/docs/installation.md#install-python, which is problematic because python 3.7 is no longer supported https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3717/